# Echo dropdown based on javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, dropbox

This website has been a great resource.  I've got the bulk of my website prototype working as planned but I've run into a snag.

I'm trying to echo data back into the dropdown of a form, but this dropdown input is based on javascript.  It sets the dropdown to a range of years and it updates each year based on the expected age of the users.

I've got the echo working on text fields and dropdowns where the list is included in the  tags of the form.

The issue I'm running into is how to echo the selection back into the form based on the javascript which generates the range of years...I'm guessing I need to echo the selection based on the output of the javascript, but I'm struggling to make it work...

Here's the code...

```js
        var min = new Date().getFullYear() - 45;
        cur = new Date().getFullYear();
        select = document.getElementById('c01');

        for (var i = min; i<=cur; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.text = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
```

```html
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM planner WHERE username = '$username'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<label for="c01">user #01</label>
<select id="c01" name="c01">
<option <?php echo ($row["c01"] === "opt")?"selected" : ""; ?></option>
</select>
```

The reason I don't just use a list of years is because I want the date range to update every year.  Hence the javascript (which I like to use).

I've read the PHP.net manual and it has come up wanting in this area.  If anybody wants to ping me about using prepared statements or PDO...I get it.  It's on my todo list, but I started this based on mysqli procedural style since it is what I'm comfortable with for now.

Obviously you don't have access to my database so we'll have to build a generic input to test the echo if somebody has some insight on how to do this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to simply print out the first value of the menu as the selected value and still append the rest of the values via javascript then should the php code not be:

```
<label for="c01">user #01</label>
<select id="c01" name="c01">
    <option value="<?=$row['c01'];?>" selected><?=$row['c01'];?></option>
</select>
```

Also is the returned resource actually a flat array ($row['c01']) or multidimensional ($row[0]['c01'])?

Comment: I want to echo the value from the server.  I've checked the data base and the values are there...I just can't get them to echo back into the drop down, which I think is due to the javascript.  The resource is flat...it's just one row per user with multiple columns for each user input.

Comment: This worked great once I fixed a few spacing errors within the PHP I screwed up....thanks again for the help!!!